# Gremlin: How to get more than 1 shortest path with same number of edges?

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to use the following script to get the shortest path:

```
g.V.filter{it.name == 'station1'}.out.dedup().loop(2){it.object.name != "station5" & it.loops < 30}.path{it.name}
```

If there are more than 1 shortest path in the graph, how do I modify the script to list all of them?

Comment: When you say that there is "more than 1 shortest path", I assume that you mean that there are multiple paths of length 2 between station1 and station5 and you want all such paths.  Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, I mean that the number of edge of alternative shortest path is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated GremlinDocs Shortest Path Recipe to perhaps better address the topic:

http://gremlindocs.com/#recipes/shortest-path

The example basically culminates in doing a path distribution:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).out.loop(1){it.object.id!="5" && it.loops< 6 }.path{it.name}.groupBy{it.size()}{it}.cap.next()
==>2=[[marko, ripple]]
==>3=[[marko, josh, ripple], [marko, lop, ripple]]
==>4=[[marko, josh, lop, ripple]]
```

Note that two paths of length 3 are shown.

Comment: Maybe I have to use dedup, seems that this solution does not work for me.

Comment: What I am implementing: http://www.flickr.com/photos/cmkpl/8826752520/ , each route between two stations is an edge

Comment: Looking at that picture, do you model the graph as their being 2 edges between "Prime View" and "Fung Tei" (one for the 614 and 614P)? I added an extra edge to the toy graph in my example between marko and josh and re-ran my solution above and it added a third path of [marko,josh,ripple] to paths length 3, so I think that it works in that scenario as well.  If you are still having problems it might help to know more about how you have specifically modelled your graph in relation to that flickr diagram.

Comment: Thanks! I use 2 edges to model between "Prime View" and "Fung Tei". I must use dedup() in my statement. Otherwise as there are loops in the graph, it will produce "nearly infinite" solution.

For example from Tai Hing (North) to Siu Hong:
`g.V.filter{it.cname == '大興(北)'}.outE.inV.dedup().loop(3){it.object.cname != "兆康" && it.loops < 30}.path{it.cname}{it.no};` should have 2 shortest path (one by the purple West Rail Line)

the dedup() function will produce only one solution even there are different routes between the same path.

Comment: Glad it is all working...nice!  btw, i just answered your other related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812679/is-it-possible-to-get-the-shortest-path-with-traversal-cost-by-using-cypher-or-g/16872807#16872807

Comment: @stephenmallette: Could you explain, what the `loop(1)` exactly means? I've seen recipes with `loop(2)` and can't pinpoint the difference.

Comment: @guerda it's like a goto.  in other words, `loop(1)` means go back one step in the pipeline and `loop(2)` means go back two steps in the pipeline.  It's arguably better to use named steps as opposed to counting backward (i.e. `out.as('x').out.loop('as')`), but for "short" loops it's more convenient.